# Xcode10 & openframework IOSno

Tags: xcode, build, clang, openframeworks

I just update to xCode10 – xCode 9 wasn't returning this error.

Whenever I try to build using openframeworks ios 10.0.0 I receive this error

```
 /clang:-1: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

but calling clang on my terminal I receive this

```
❯ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.2) . 
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered a similar issue with building in xCode 10 as well. Following the steps (both removing the flags for quicktime and in my case removing references to the i386 architecture build settings) here fixed it for me: https://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/xcode-10-0-build-errors/30447

Hope this helps!